# How to convert GPT volume to MBR on Windows 8

Tags: mbr

My problem is convert `GPT` volume not disk. I found some solutions but they are all about how to convert disk. On my windows 8, it has `disk 0`. `disk 0` has `7` volumes. I just want to convert one volume in `disk 0` . How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think your question is on-topic here since it doesn't seem to be a programming question. I'm also not sure that your question makes sense since, so far as I'm aware, GPT and MBR are all about how the physical disk is divided up into sections - it doesn't make sense to only change one of those sections of the disk from one to the other.

Comment: Disk 0 is not allowed to convert gpt to mbr because of other volumes.But there is 600 gb area free I want to convert it to mbr so I can format the PC to win 7 from win 8. Is there any way to convert volume to mbr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution. I delete the disks with Gparted. I download from http://gparted.org/download.php and copy to dvd as bootable. I boot the PC and divide the partitions as NTFS. That's all.